# Synonym for "isn't truly happy with who he is"?

Tags: synonyms

What would be an appropriate, more condensed way to say "isn't truly happy with who he is" without having the negative in the sentence? This sentence is part of an essay where I discuss how a character tries to escape from reality and makes himself seem better than he really is.

Thank you

Comment: Self-doubting, self-hating, self-despising?

Comment: I can't think of a single term other than those beginning in self-. Maybe you should isolate the reason why the character isn't happy with themselves. Are they regretful, etc?

Comment: "Uncomfortable with himself".

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like he's not **comfortable in his own skin**

> (idiomatic) Relaxed and confident in one's manner of presenting oneself and interacting with others; conveying the impression that one has a clear, satisfying understanding of one's own abilities and situation.
>
> [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/comfortable_in_one%27s_own_skin)

Comment: That still has a "not", though.

Answer (score 3):

How about **unfulfilled**?

From the [Cambridge English Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unfulfilled):

> ​unhappy because you ​think you should be ​achieving more in ​your ​life

Answer (score 2):

**malcontent**

> adjective
>
> 1.
>   not satisfied or content with currently prevailing conditions or circumstances.
>
> 2.
>   dissatisfied with the existing government, administration, system, etc.
>
> noun
>
> 3.
>   a malcontent person, especially one who is chronically discontented or dissatisfied.

Answer (score 0):

You might say that he was somewhat ***unsettled*** with regards to himself.

Answer (score 0):

You could say he's **infected with self-doubt** or simply just **depressed** (I've never met a depressed person who was *truly happy* with anything, and they usually blame themselves more than their circumstances).

One symptom of such a state is that an individual may become **clingy**—i.e. overly dependent upon the praise of others for feelings of self-worth.

Such a man's poor view of himself may be fueled by an underlying, persistent **anxious** feeling that makes him so universally **uncomfortable** regardless of the outside world that he begins to believe himself to be **defective.** For example, if the story is told from his perspective, you could use a neat little trick and just describe your character as "defective"—letting the reader infer that is the character's own opinion of himself, and not the narrator's.

You could refer to his state by its early causes, a long-ago **shame** or deep **regret** he still holds onto. One standard implication of a man being shameful or regretful is that he's not truly happy with himself.

Answer (score 0):

**Insecure?**

> 1. Uncertain or anxious about oneself; not confident
>
> http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/insecure

Answer (score 0):

***angst-ridden***?

> : filled with deep anxiety, especially about oneself or about the nature of existence [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/angst-ridden)

Answer (score 0):

Such a person may be suffering from an [***identity crisis***](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20identity%20crisis&ie=&oe=):

> a period of uncertainty and confusion in which a person's sense of identity becomes insecure, typically due to a change in their expected aims or role in society.

Answer (score 0):

**discontent with himself?**

Or disappointed with himself? Dissatisfied?

I guess this question hinges on how you define happy.